# Rails (routes.rb) Routing For Controllers - Confused on how to route correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have read [the rails tutorial for routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and frankly I am more confused than when I went in.

I have generated new controllers via "rails generate  " for my vanilla rails application, and I have no idea how to correctly map to the index of these new controllers. I got it working before, but it seemed extremely hacky so I am asking to confirm I am learning the right thing, and not 'tricks' to get things working.

I have several controllers:

- Sponsors
- Committee
- Home
- Pages
- Users
- Events

And I have a navigation partial on the home controller's index.html.haml page from the associated action (I think). My problem is, I am trying to link using `link_to` to these new controllers and their respective index actions and I am getting errors such as:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Home#index
No route matches {:controller=>"sponsors", :action=>"index", :class=>nil}
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/home/index.html.haml
```

I can remove the errors by adding `resources :sponsors ...` to my `routes.rb` but is this the correct approach? I don't want my controllers index being accessed via `url.com/controller/index` but rather `url.com/controller` - and everything so far requires I link to `url.com/controller/index`.

I take it I require a:

```
def index
end
```

In each of the controller `.rb` files, but then the problem above arises. You don't access google.com by typing in google.com/index, so how do I tell rails that I don't want my controllers being accessed via /index? The only way I see this being done is without a

```
def index
end
```

In each of the controller `.rb` files.

### Here's my routes.rb

```
KCC::Application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  get "home/index"

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root to: 'home#index'
```

### Here's my Navigation Menu, which should help with clarifying what I want to link to

```
%li
    = link_to "Sponsors", :controller => "sponsors", :action => "index", :class => ( "active" if params[:controller] == "sponsors" )
                -#%a{ :href => "/sponsors" } Sponsors
                -#= "active" if params[:controller] == "home" 
%li
    = link_to "Events", :controller => "events", :action => "index", :class => ( "active" if params[:controller] == "events" )
                -#%a{ :href => "/events" } Events
%li
    = link_to "Committee", :controller => "committee", :action => "index", :class => ( "active" if params[:controller] == "committee" )
                -#%a{ :href => "/committee" } Committee
%li
    = link_to "Membership", :controller => "pages", :action => "membership", :class => ( "active" if params[:controller] == "pages" )
                -#%a{ :href => "/membership" } Membership
%li
    = link_to "About", :controller => "pages", :action => "about", :class => ( "active" if params[:controller] == "pages" )
                -#%a{ :href => "/about" } About
%li
    = link_to "Contact", :controller => "pages", :action => "contact", :class => ( "active" if params[:controller] == "pages" )
                -#%a{ :href => "/contact" } Contact
%li#join
    = link_to "Join", :controller => "users", :action => "join", :class => ( "active" if params[:controller] == "users" )
                -#%a{ :href => "/contact" } Join
%li#signin
    = link_to "Sign In", :controller => "users", :action => "signin", :class => ( "active" if params[:controller] == "users" )
                -#%a{ :href => "/contact" } Sign In
```

Comment: run `rake routes` in console and see what are the url defined in your routes.rb now just add `_path` or `_url` at suffix of that url something like for `index` `committees_path`

Answer (score 1):

Must define route in your routes.rb file like

```
get "controller/action"
```

let me take an another example from your controller and its action.
When ever you write any custom methods and want to customize your own route instead of any controller name and its action name. must define your route this way

```
match 'sponser-list' => "sponsors#index", :as => :sponsors ,via: [:get]
```

this way no one can trace your controller and action name... give custom route name as i show you "sponser-list". so you will have

> url.com/sponser-list

this could be with any action and controller.

and than you can access.

Do rake routes and you will have your route, use it by apending _path behind it. like sponsors_path.

Comment: FYI `match` is depreciated in rails4 never prefer to use that

Comment: In rails 4 you can use it but you have to specify via: [:get] and as: :route_name. On routes, the match method will no longer act as a catch-all option. You should now specify which HTTP verb to respond to with the option :via. it will act as you want to do with any routes.